# Teacher Community - Using CS50 for AP

Tags: ap-cs-principles

I will be teaching AP Computer Science Principals this fall for the first time. I've decided to use the CS50 curriculum. (partially due to [Curriculum choice for AP Computer Science Principles](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/1157/curriculum-choice-for-ap-computer-science-principles))

Is there (or are there multiple) teacher communities around providing support for using CS50 to teach AP CSP?

Comment: Welcome to CSEd! You've come to the right place :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is an email group dedicated to CS50 AP administered by Harvard. Reach out to the CS50 AP team (info [here](https://ap.cs50.net/)), and they will get you connected there. It has been an invaluable resource for me the past two years as I’ve been teaching their curriculum.

Feel free to reach out (and post here!) if you have further questions about CS50 AP. I am a strong believer in the curriculum and the people behind it.

Comment: Also, a general page about bringing CS50 AP to your school can be found [here](https://docs.cs50.net/2016/ap/resources/teaching/teaching.html).

Comment: That CS50 site doesn't seem to exist any more. Has it gone elsewhere?

Answer (score 6):

The APCS community maintains an active web site and mailing list. It has many users who ask and answer many questions.

Start here to learn more: https://apcommunity.collegeboard.org. Find your community from there. Note that the site has separate lists for APCSA and APCSP. You can join several of the communities.

You need to join (free) and then just ask for the experience of others with CS50.